# When passing value to render in adminhtml shows blank page - Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7

I am trying to fetch the value from a table and display it in adminhtml. But it's showing me the blank page. With this below is my code within

```
Vendorname/modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Manager/Renderer/
```

I have placed a file FormMessage.php

```
 <?php
   namespace Cubet\RMA\Block\Adminhtml\Manager\Edit\Renderer;

   class FormMessage extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
{
    protected $_msgmodel;

    public function __construct(
      \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $factory,
      \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
      \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper,
      \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
      \Vendorname\Modulename\Model\ListMessage $msgmodel,
      \Vendorname\Modulename\Helper\Data $helper,
    $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($factory, $collectionFactory, $escaper, $data);
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    $this->_helper = $helper;
    $this->_msgmodel = $msgmodel;
}
public function getElementHtml()
{
    // $request_id = $this->getEscapedValue();
    $request_id = 1;
    // $this->_logger->debug($request_id);
    $html = parent::getElementHtml();
    $html = $this->getRMAMessage($request_id);
    return $html;
}

private function getRMAMessage($request_id)
{ 
    $data = $this->_helper->getRMAMessages($request_id);
    $return = "<div id='table-rmamessages'>";
    foreach ($data->getData() as $row) {
        $this->_logger->debug(print_r($row, 1));
        $return .= "<div class='col-from'>".$row['message']."</div>";
    }
     $return .= "</div>";
    return $return;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you set developer mode ? If you have blank page it's probably because you have an error OR you did `getData()` / `debug()` and you have too much data to display.

For enable developer mode you can do this `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`.

Tell me if it's ok for you.

Enjoy,

Yannig Smagghe.